# Attempting to implement a parser for a regex

Tags: regex, syntax

We were given the regular expression:

```
<expr> -> <term> { (+|-) <term>
<term> -> <factor> { (*|/) <factor>
<factor> -> num | '(' <expr> ')' | -<factor>
```

A correct input was also given as `1 + 2 * (3 - 2) + -2 * 3`
and I don't know how you can jump over the * | / to be able to start with a +|- expression. Also would like to know what the "{}" imply.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer thanks to a colleague. The "{}" imply zero or more times so you can effectively skip the call to term and go straight to factor.